# Power management on Android — is app CPU correlated to power usage?

Tags: battery-life

2 questions:

1. Is application CPU usage on Android correlated and how highly to battery usage? In other words, are apps that suck a lot of CPU also draining the battery or not necessarily?
2. Is there a way to itemize and display the phone's power use by application, at any given point in time as well as within defined time buckets and maybe view charts and such? Sort of like a diagnostic monitor for power usage by application or system component?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. CPU is not the only thing using power but definitely a major one (when not idling).
2. Most Android devices have a 'Battery' section in settings which lists what applications are using up your battery. I think it gets reset every time you plug in a recharger. There might be 3rd party apps which collect that information over longer term and display it moer pretty.